# How to best import and process very large csv files with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, delayed-job

I am building a rails app that I am deploying with Heroku, and I need to be able to import and process large csv files (5000+ lines).

Doing it in the controller using the built in ruby csv parser takes over 30 seconds and causes the Heroku dyno to time out

I was thinking of putting the csv into the database then processing it with a delayed_job but this method limits out at just over 4200 lines.

I am using mysql and longtext for the column containing the file so the db should be able to handle it

Any ideas for this use case?

Comment: You could split the CSV into several files, or simply use a Worker to actually parse the CSV and store the data and respond directly to the user that "Your CSV is being parsed, come back in few minutes".

Comment: tried that, sending the file to the worker causes an active record error since it is too large for the delayed jobs table

Comment: My process is basically to have the controller save the file and do any operations that potentially involve enormous files in a background process / worker. If you parse the file line by line or in batch it should not cause an active record error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- to import csv faster, my suggestion is using gem smarter_csv, you can cek from their website [tilo/smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)
- as stated from their site: > smarter_csv is a Ruby Gem for smarter importing of CSV Files as Array(s) of Hashes, suitable for direct processing with Mongoid or ActiveRecord, and parallel processing with Resque or Sidekiq
- I use this gem and combined with resque

below is sample code to import file

```
  n = SmarterCSV.process(params[:file].path) do |chunk|
    Resque.enqueue(ImportDataMethod, chunk)
  end
```

after it read file, passed the data record to resque and then import it in background (if you using rails 4.2 above you can combine with rails active job)